# vscode [ctrl+click] 'vue single-file components', 'go to definition' not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

```
// src/ui/tabbar/Index.vue
<template>
  <div>
    my-tabbar
  </div>
</template>

// src/ui/index.js
import MyTabbar from './tabbar/Index.vue'

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.component(MyTabbar.name, MyTabbar)
  }
}

// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(ui)

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

// src/App.vue
<template>
  // [ctrl + click] my-tabbar tips no definition found for 'my-tabbar'
  <my-tabbar>/<my-tabbar>
</template>
```

vscode [ctrl+click] 'vue single-file components', 'go to definition' not working

How can I [ctrl + click]  to jump to 'src/ui/tabbar/Index.vue'

Can you tell me anything you know? thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

I used [vue-helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenjiaolong.vue-helper) extension, together with [volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar).

Answer (score 0):

Both [vue-helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenjiaolong.vue-helper) and [Vetur-extended](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zardoy.vetur-extended) seems to work.

I personally prefer **Vetur-extended** because it seems a bit faster than the **vue-helper**.