# Go To definition does not work in same file with VSCODE + VETUR

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur, go-to-definition

My vue.js configuration is

- vue.js 2.0
- use vue.cli
- webpack
- javascript not typescript
- use multiple root

  - server : server project
  - client/dashboard : web client project(this is vue project)

On follow code, "go definition" does not work with "could not find definition"

```
<template>
<div>
<button @click="clickEvent"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    clickEvent() {
      this.function1()
      ...
    },
    function1() {
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

- when go to definition on @click="clickEvent"
- when go to definition on this.function1()
- computed, props is same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vetur` is look like no this function. Maybe you can try use `vue-helper`.

[image]

Comment: This was only solution working for me with Framework 7 + Vue + Cordova. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **vue-helper** or **Vetur-extended**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76565821/13147506

Answer (score -1):

You can try this extension: js-jumper